# setFullScreenIntent equivalent on iOS

Tags: android, ios, notifications, android-notifications

Android has a `setFullScreenIntent()` function that allows to bring an Activity to the foreground (e.g. for Alarm/Calls).

Is there any way to achieve the same result (even partly) on iOS?

I have understood that it is not, but I would like a confirmation about this.

Thanks !

(See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean))